# How to set cookie if user has no session?

Tags: php, session, cookies, model-view-controller, set

I am making a webshop and now I am stuck at the shopping-cart. 
Simple explanation of what my idea is:
If visitor has NO session and add the product to shoppingcart, set cookie with the data I give the cookie. If user has a session active and add a product to shoppingcart, save to database. The thing with user has session works fine, but I dont know what to do for setting the cookie. I am working in a MVC (flight). 
Controller-code:

```
public function shopProduct()
{
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    $productname = $_POST['productname'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        if (strlen($product) < 1) {
            $err['data'] = array("status" => "failed", "return" => "Er is iets misgegaaqn!");
        } else {
            if (setcookie("basket_save", $product, $productname, $color, $price, time() + 30000000, "/")) {
                $err['data'] = array("status" => "success", "return" => "Dit product is toegevoegd aan uw winkelwagen.");
            } else {
                $err['data'] = array("status" => "failed", "return" => "Er is iets misgegaan!");
            }
        }

    } else if (strlen($userid) < 1) {
        $err['data'] = array("status" => "failed", "return" => "Er is iets misgegaaqn!");
    } else {
        $OrderModel = new OrderModel();
        if ($OrderModel->addBasket($userid, $product, $productname, $color, $price)) {
            $err['data'] = array("status" => "success", "return" => "Dit product is toegevoegd aan uw winkelwagen.");
        } else {
            $err['data'] = array("status" => "failed", "return" => "Er is iets misgegaan!");
        }
    }
    exit($err['endpoint'] = json_encode($err['data'], $options = 0));
}
```

So my question is, what did I type wrong in the cookie-lines what is regretting the cookie for setting itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the how one should use set cookie (from php.net reference )
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )

and in your code

setcookie("basket_save", $product, $productname, $color, $price, time() + 30000000, "/"))

there are like 4 parameters of value , (i.e wrong arguments are passed to the function) $productname refer to expire .

so make it like 
$arrCok = [$product, $productname, $color, $price];

setcookie("basket_save",$arrCok , time() + 30000000, "/"))

or set each cookie for a value you want to save.

Comment: I tried that code but aint got success. If I do like $arrCok = $productname; and vardump the cookie I get: ["basket_save"]=> string(34) "Right Value"